# How can I use list comprehension to replace a comma with an escaped comma in a list that contains strings and numbers

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a tuple that contains elements that are both strings and numbers, and I am trying to replace a comma that exists in one of the elements of the tuple with an escaped comma, e.g. the input looks like the following

```
('', 'i_like_cats', 'I like, cookies', 10319708L, "* / Item ID='10319708'", 'i_wish_was_an_oscar_meyer_weiner',
0.101021321)
```

and what I want as output is

```
('', 'i_like_cats', 'I like\, cookies', 10319708L, "* / Item ID='10319708'", 'i_wish_was_an_oscar_meyer_weiner',
0.101021321)
```

What I want to do is replace the , after like with /, because I'm outputting the content to a csv file, so when the next step of the pipeline reads the file it splits the file at the comma between 'like' and 'cookies' even though I don't want it to.  I am unable to modify the code of the downstream part of the pipeline so I can't switch to something like a semicolon or tab delimited file, and I can't change.

What I've tried to do is use list comprehension to solve this as follows

```
line = map(lambda x: str.replace(x, '"', '\"'), line)
```

but that generates a type error indicating that replace requires a string object but it received a long.

The only solution I can think of is to break the tuple down into it's individual elements, modify the element that contains the comma, and then build a new tuple and append each of the elements back on, but it seems like there has to be a more pythonic way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a tuple not a list, second can you give a clear example of what you have as input and what you want as output ?

Comment: Are you sure the downstream won't parse it properly if you enclose the field in double quotes?

Comment: I just checked and I'm sure it won't parse properly if I enclose the field in double quotes.

Comment: If you're outputting to a `.csv`, are you using Python's csv module? If you set its `quoting` attribute appropriately it should take care of this for you - by default it's set to a quoting behavior that will quote strings containing the delimiter, but if you set it to `QUOTE_NONE` and have an escape character set it'll use that.

Comment: No, I'll try that.

Comment: Actually, I misidentified the problem - it's not that field, it's another one.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Is it only one specific field then?  Can it be identified by position or content?

Comment: You could also do: `line = map(lambda x: str.replace(x, '"', '\"') if isinstance(x, str) else x, line)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think list comprehension works the best for apply a rule for every element; if you know which single string you would like to change, why can't you just change that single one?

If you want to change all comma into escaped comma, probably try this out:

```
strtuple = ('', 'i_like_cats', 'I like, cookies', 10319708, "* / Item ID='10319708'", 'i_wish_was_an_oscar_meyer_weiner',
0.101021321)
converted_strlist = [i.replace(',', '\\,') if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in strtuple]
```

Comment: please format your code next time with 4 spaces in front of your code lines. If you wish to you can just highlight your code and hit `ctrl`+`k`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to verify an element is a `str` instance before calling replace on it.

Something like:

```
    data = (
        '',
        'i_like_cats',
        'I like, cookies',
        10319708L,
        "* / Item ID='10319708'",
        'i_wish_was_an_oscar_meyer_weiner',
        0.101021321,
    )

    line = [
        x.replace(",", "\,") if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in data
    ]
```

Comment: That verification is already present verbatim in the accepted answer (see the last line of their code).